# Sections not displaying underneath

Tags: html, css, sections

I'm relatively new to coding and trying to create my WordPress home page in HTML & CSS, this is my home page https://danieljmanning.co.uk

I've added the nav bar and the home page but every time I try to add a section underneath this hero section it displays at the top of the page instead of underneath the hero section.

I expected my info section to display underneath the hero banner container the same as my home page on https://danieljmanning.co.uk

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>danieljmanning - WordPress Web Designer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="description" content="Daniel Manning's Web Design, SEO optimisation and blog writing services. 
    Do you want to rank #1? Get In Touch Today!">
    <style>
        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p{
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <img src="/images/danieljmanning_logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" aria-label="danieljmanning's home page"></a>Home</li>
            <li><a href="#" aria-label="More about who Daniel Manning is and more about his experience 
                in web design and SEO Optimisation"></a>About</li>
            <li><a href="#" aria-label="Daniel Manning's Portfolio Page"></a>Portfolio</li>
            <li><a href="#" aria-label="Web Design, SEO Optimisation and Monthly Support Services 
                with pricing and detail"></a>Services</li>
            <li><a href="#" aria-label="Blog Listing Page"></a>Blog</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn">Apply Now</button>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
        <h1>DANIELJMANNING</h1>
        <h2>AFFORDABLE WORDPRESS WEB DESIGN</h3>
            <p>I am Daniel J Manning <span class="p-home">here to help you earn more</span> for your business with a 
                website! <span class="p-home">Scroll Down to See My Work.</span></p>
            <button class="portfolio-btn">PORTFOLIO</button>
            <button class="apply-btn">APPLY</button>
    </div>
</div>
<section class="info">
    <h1>Earn more with a website</h1>
    <p>Having a website gives you a forefront, a place where visitors can find you, giving them the opportunity to come 
        to your business.</p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*FindOutWhatthismeans*/
}

.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.1px solid #303030;
}

.logo{
    width: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn{
    display: flex;
    width: 190px;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.content{
    margin-top: 22%;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content h1{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.content h2{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: rgb(47, 193, 255);
    font-size: 18px;
}

.content p{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.p-home{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-btn{
    display: flex;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.portfolio-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    border: 1px;
    outline: 1px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    
}

.apply-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.info{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right. The problem is that you have added `position: fixed;` to the **container**, so this will result in pinning/fixing the **container** class relative to the viewport, thus the **info** div will be positioned underneath the **container** div.

I have fixed your code as follows:

1. I have removed the positioning properties from .container class.
2. I have added `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to maintain the original layout (you can change it if you want).
3. I have added `background-color: black;` to the nav since it was moved outside the .container div (I don't think you really need it to be in the container div).
4. I have fixed some HTML tags issues (some tags were not closed properly, check if the tags are closed as you wanted).

I suggest reading this MDN docs about positions:

[Position docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*FindOutWhatthismeans*/
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* newly added to center the content */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 0.1px solid #303030;
  
  /* newly added since the nav was moved outside the container classs */
  background-color: black;
}

.logo {
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 55px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.content h1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.content h2 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: rgb(47, 193, 255);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content p {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.p-home {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.portfolio-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border: 1px;
  outline: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.apply-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.info {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="/images/danieljmanning_logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="danieljmanning's home page"></a>Home</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="More about who Daniel Manning is and more about his experience 
                    in web design and SEO Optimisation"></a>About</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Daniel Manning's Portfolio Page"></a>Portfolio</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Web Design, SEO Optimisation and Monthly Support Services 
                    with pricing and detail"></a>Services</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Blog Listing Page"></a>Blog</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn">Apply Now</button>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>DANIELJMANNING</h1>
    <h2>AFFORDABLE WORDPRESS WEB DESIGN</h3>
      <p>I am Daniel J Manning <span class="p-home">here to help you earn more</span> for your business with a website! <span class="p-home">Scroll Down to See My Work.</span></p>
      <button class="portfolio-btn">PORTFOLIO</button>
      <button class="apply-btn">APPLY</button>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="info">
  <h1>Earn more with a website</h1>
  <p>Having a website gives you a forefront, a place where visitors can find you, giving them the opportunity to come to your business.</p>
</section>

<h1>a website</h1>
<p>Having a website gives you a forefront, a place where visitors can find you, giving them the opportunity to come to your business.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: I have replaced the code with these snippets, my header is now on the left, with the content to the right of that in the middle and my info section to the right of that so everything is now in the middle of the screen going across from each other instead of in the correct places.

Comment: if you run the code snippet in the answer you will see the content is stacked. Is this code running in another container or something?

Comment: The navigation, container and earn-container all went across the screen when using your exact code. I've managed to work it out now with the documentation you provided (thank you for that). Both containers needed padding added to them and the "container" element had to be set to relative. Once this was done everything was normal a showing correctly.

Comment: Great, good to hear